# Why is my java class not connecting to remote drive using smb (When correct username and password is used)?

Tags: java, eclipse, networking, smb

Why is my java class not connecting to remote drive using smb?

```
    String user = "user1";
    String pass ="pass234";

    String sharedFolder="c$\\WebDocs2\\AutoFrameworkResults\\";
    String path= "smb:" +"\\" + "\\192.xx.1.xx\\" + sharedFolder + "Example.txt";
    NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication("",user, pass);
    SmbFile smbFile = new SmbFile(path,auth);
    SmbFileOutputStream smbfos = new SmbFileOutputStream(smbFile);
    smbfos.write("testing....and writing to a file".getBytes());
    System.out.println("completed ...nice !");
```

Im getting the following Exception (But the username and password credentials are correct)?`

```
Exception in thread "main" jcifs.smb.SmbAuthException: Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.
    at jcifs.smb.SmbSession.sessionSetup(SmbSession.java:406)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbSession.send(SmbSession.java:218)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbTree.treeConnect(SmbTree.java:176)
```

Comment: Put up a [mcve] please. And maybe maybe because the user is unknown or the password isn't matching?

Comment: @Jens i have tried removing the first set of \\ but thats not the problem :/

Comment: @Jens this is not a duplicate because i have followed the instructions listed in the ticket yet still face a username and password problem

Comment: Try to change  `new NtlmPasswordAuthentication("",user, pass)` to `new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(user+":"+pass)`

Comment: @Eritrean thanks for your comment im afraid it didnt work